# Enumeration of BPP machines

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

Can we enumerate all probabilistic Turing machines (with bounded error), like we do for deterministic Turing machines (when using diagonalization arguments against deterministic Turing machines)? If not, does this mean we cannot diagonalize against BPP machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Enumerate over all pairs $(M,p)$ of probabilistic Turing machines $M$ and polynomials $p$. Interpret each such pair in the following way: on input $x$, run $M$ for $p(|x|)$ steps, and if it doesn't halt, output "yes".

Comment: If $M$ doesn’t halt after $p(|x|)$ steps, shouldn’t we output “no” instead of “yes”?

Comment: It doesn't matter what we output in that case. We could also toss a coin.

Comment: Also, why is the set of probabilistic Turing machines $M$ enumerable? Can we map it to natural numbers like deterministic Turing machines?

Comment: It's exactly the same thing. If you can describe an object as a string, you can enumerate over all descriptions in order to enumerate over all objects.

Comment: It’s not immediately clear to me why a probabilistic Turing machine can be represented as a string. Would you not need to specify the transition probabilities and wouldn’t you have to worry about how to represent these probabilities (eg: represent them to what precision?). Also, since probabilities are real numbers and real numbers are not enumerable, how do you enumerate over machines with different transition probabilities?

Comment: You might be able to cheat if you use arbitrary probabilities. In fact, in complexity theory we often tacitly assume that probabilities are of the form $a/2^b$ (or at the very least rational), though when describing algorithms we allow arbitrary probabilities. As long as all probabilities used are computable, the difference is pretty minor, and in particular, classes like BPP stay the same under all reasonable definitions.

Comment: In other words, for BPP machines, we can consider that the transition probabilities are rational numbers, without the loss of any generality? Just for the sake of completeness, is there a proof of this?

Comment: Just approximate the probabilities well enough. The resulting distribution will be very similar, so if you had (say) a 2/3 promise, now you’ll get a (say) 3/5 promise.

Comment: A quick follow-up: if it is undecidable to find out if a probabilistic Turing machine either accepts with probability at least 2/3 or rejects with probability at most 1/3 for every input, how can we hope to enumerate such machines? By "enumerate", do we just mean having an ordered list of such machines and we do not care whether we can efficiently generate this list?

Comment: We enumerate over all probabilistic polytime Turing machines. These include all BPP machines.